# Java arraylist accessing an element to calculate average

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a program that reads numbers from a file and calculates the average of them. However, I am getting the error shown below at run-time. I tried to fix it using the casting to double as shown in the code but it did not help.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:34)
    at __SHELL40.run(__SHELL40.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:34)
    at __SHELL41.run(__SHELL41.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:33)
    at __SHELL42.run(__SHELL42.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:33)
    at __SHELL43.run(__SHELL43.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner("n.txt");
            File file = new File(input.nextLine());
            input = new Scanner(file);
            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();

            int index=1;

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();;
                numbers.add(line);
                System.out.println(index + " : " + line);
                index++;
            }
            input.close();

            double sum = 0.0;
            double average;
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++)  
            {
                sum = sum + (double) numbers.get(j) ;  //My guess is that this line is invoking the error

            }
            average = sum/numbers.size();
            System.out.println(average);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list `numbers` contains `String` objects, so casting the elements to `double` will throw an exception. You could have avoided this runtime exception if you had used the generic type `ArrayList` properly:

```
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This would allow the compiler to detect ahead of time the type incompatibility.

To read the double value of the string, you can use `Double#parseDouble(String)`:

```
 sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(numbers.get(j));
```

Alternatively you can change the type parameter of `numbers` to `Double` and convert the value when adding the element to the list:

```
ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();

...
numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
```